# How to make "=" sign work on my java-calculator

Tags: java

I have been trying to create a (ugly) calculator and I am having problems with "=" sign. I know how to convert numbers (in string) to numbers (in int), but the problem here is mainly */-+. I have absolutely no idea what to do when they are added to the situation.

Here is a gif of the calculator: http://gyazo.com/98781eaaca0b3152967e6370cad3df15

```
package megetenkelkalkis;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*; 

class Kalkulator extends JFrame{
    private String textfield = ""; 
    private String replace =""; 
    private JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");
    private JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
    private JButton btn2 = new JButton("2"); 
    private JButton btn3 = new JButton("3"); 
    private JButton btn4 = new JButton("4"); 
    private JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
    private JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
    private JButton btn7 = new JButton("7"); 
    private JButton btn8 = new JButton("8"); 
    private JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");
    private JButton btnlik = new JButton("=");
    private JButton btngange = new JButton("*");
    private JButton btndele = new JButton("/");
    private JButton btnpluss = new JButton("+");
    private JButton btnminus = new JButton("-");
    private JTextField tekst = new JTextField(); 

    private JButton btndel= new JButton("DEL");

    JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel(); 

 public Kalkulator(String tittel){
 tekst.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(310,25));
 setTitle(tittel); 
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
 p.add(btn0);
 p.add(btn1);
 p.add(btn2);
 p.add(btn3);
 p.add(btn4);
 p.add(btn5);
 p.add(btnlik);
 p2.add(btn6);
 p2.add(btn7);
 p2.add(btn8);
 p2.add(btn9);
 p2.add(btndele); 
 p2.add(btngange);
 p2.add(btnpluss);
 p2.add(btnminus); 
 p3.add(tekst); 
 p3.add(btndel); 
 add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
 add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
 add(p3, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
 pack(); 

 Knappelytter knappelytteren = new Knappelytter(); 
 btn0.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn1.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn2.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn3.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn4.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn5.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn6.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn7.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn8.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btn9.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btnlik.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btndele.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btngange.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btnminus.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btnpluss.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 btndel.addActionListener(knappelytteren);
 }
 class Knappelytter implements ActionListener{
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent  hendelse){

 JButton valgtKnapp = (JButton) hendelse.getSource(); 
 String knapp = valgtKnapp.getText(); 

 if (knapp.equals("0")){
     textfield += "0"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("1")){
     textfield += "1"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("2")){
     textfield += "2"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("3")){
     textfield += "3"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("4")){
     textfield += "4"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("5")){
     textfield += "5"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("6")){
     textfield += "6"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("7")){
     textfield += "7"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("8")){
     textfield += "8"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("9")){
     textfield += "9"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("*")){
     textfield += "*"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("/")){
     textfield += "/"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("-")){
     textfield += "-"; 
 tekst.setText(textfield);

 }else if(knapp.equals("+")){


        textfield += "+"; 
     tekst.setText(textfield);

     }else if(knapp.equals("DEL")){ 
     tekst.setText(" "); 
     textfield = " "; 

     }else if(knapp.equals("=")){ 
     else if(knapp.equals("=")){ 
/EDIT RIGHT HERE
String[] parts = textfield.split("-*/+");

for (int i = 0; i < textfield.length(); i++){
if (textfield.charAt(i) == ('-')){
String one = parts[0];
String two = parts[1]; 
int one1 = Integer.parseInt(one); 
int one2 = Integer.parseInt(two);
int one3 = one1-one2; 
String one4 = String.valueOf(one3);
tekst.setText(one4); 
     }
     }
 }

 }



public class MegetEnkelKalkis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Kalkulator Skole = new Kalkulator("Kalkulator"); 
        Skole.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the Input
2. Seperate it from the Operands ( *, /, -, + )
3. Cast the strings to int's ( Integer.valueOf() throws a NumberFormatException)
4. Do a if else for the operands and then multiply, divide, add or substract the ints

Comment: I tried this a little bit, but I couldn't get it to work. I hate using []tables because most often something is wrong, but it never tells my why. My syntax is right but something else is wrong.

Comment: But I don't understand this code. Don't you think you can edit my small code to make it work? else if(knapp.equals("+")){


        textfield += "+"; 
     tekst.setText(textfield);

     }else if(knapp.equals("DEL")){ 
     tekst.setText(" "); 
     textfield = " "; 

     }else if(knapp.equals("=")){ 
     else if(knapp.equals("=")){

Comment: Now I added this code, under the if else knapp.equals(DEL). I only need to do two buttons by the way. 2*2 is fine, and I don't need 2*2*2.

Comment: eh it doesnt hurt if it's able to :) by the way it doesnt work with negative numbers. you would have to implement that yourself.

Comment: [Kalkulator.java](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11842717/) and [MegetEnkelKalkis.java](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11842710/)

I simplified the Code a bit and fixed every bug i saw.

Comment: wow. that is some huge amount of code(that I don't understand). I thank you for doing it for every number but the reason i only needed to do 2 numbers is because my book told me to only do two (because at my level I shall only be able to do two). It's not so much about getting the calculator to work and look super nice but more about to understand a simple code that could split a string, and then take out the operators and multiply them. I will give you a thumb up for your work though

Comment: I updated [doCalculation()](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11842969/) to fit your needs better. If you have any further Questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a string calculator. You basically parse the contents of textfield following the regular maths rules. It is a bit of work but not too hard.

Basically just follow this:

- Recursion might be quite suitable for that, so build a function that takes a string and returns the result as an int.
- Search for all occurrences of a parameter (e.g. *) starting with the highest priority ones (* and /)
- If you encounter that parameter split the string there into two halves (left of the parameter and right of the parameter)
- Recursively follow the same rules with the left and right part of the string.
- If the String only contains one number, parse that number using Integer.parseInt() and return it.
- Calculate the result of left operator right, so e.g. left * right, if the operator is *
- Return the result of the calculation.

Comment: Okey. I think I will try this because I haven't done it before. What do you think of, from the start, what if I put the number strings, and the operators into different strings, and then add them to the textbox. Then they are seperated from the start of, and no need to seperate them.

Comment: It's better if you let the user enter the whole thing and then calculate it. It's easier for you and the user. Also, if you liked the answer, please accept it (the green checkmark)

Answer (score 0):

Or you calculate via nashorn (javascript) engine ;)

```
private ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
double result = (double) scriptEngine.eval(formula)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build a [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), which is the easiest way to parse and evaluate methmatical formulas.  there are plenty of examples how to do that in Java on the web.

Answer (score 0):

There are  anumber of ways to do this, but recommendation is that you create two doubles. When the user clicks +,-,\ or * parse the number before it into a double. Thenwhen they press = parse everything between + and = into a double, then perform the calculation using those two doubles and output the result. You can set a flag to determine which operation to perform. for example the + button could set a boolean called Plus = true; Then when you perform the operation check which bools are true. IF more or less than one, tell the user the input was invalid, otherwise perform the operation

Comment: Could you check the edit in my OP and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I havent used Java in a while but it looks like you are overwriting the strings with just the last number, rather than adding them. IE 1234 would read produce a string that reads '4'. If that isnt happening to you then everything else looks fine with the edit. If it is, simply append the character to the end of the string before parsing it into an int. You can do this using String.Append(character[i]) I think.

Comment: I HATE tables so much, because I always get an error when I run the program but nothing in the syntax. I can post an error-screenshot for you later to see if you are still interested.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely lot of scope of improvement in the code, as suggested by others, but if you want to keep it as it is and working, then here is the code:

```
.
.
.
}else if(knapp.equals("=")){ 
 String nytekst = textfield; 
 ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 try {
    Double result = (Double) engine.eval(nytekst);
    System.out.println(result);
    tekst.setText(result.toString());
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
.
.
.
```

Comment: I know there is lots of improvements to be had in my code, but I want the feeling of having done it myself so I don't want to change anything. Your code is way above my level (At least I have never seen that stuff before). Could you check why my code in my edit is not working?

Comment: what should I look at? Did you change anything? I dont see any code in your "equal to" else if.

Comment: I changed what happened after: else if(knapp.equals("=")){. I haven't eaten today and the time is 5 in the day the day. That migh't be a problem.